# Debug the Segment Fault in C

Tags: c

I am trying to make a sorted linked list. Everything looks fine, but I am getting a Segment Fault for some reason, not sure why. Any help would be appreciated. The problem lies in my `while` loop, I have commented that in the code below.

```
typedef struct node{
    char *name;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node* insert_node(node *head, char *name){
    node *temp, *pre, *next;
    temp = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->name = name;
    temp->next = NULL;

    if (!head){
        head = temp;
    } else {
        pre = NULL;
        next = head;
        //something is wrong with this while loop, not sure what though
        while(next && (strcmp(next->name, name) < 0) ){
            pre = next;
            next = next->next;
        }
        printf("out\n");
        if (!next){
            pre->next = temp;
        } else {
            if(pre){
                temp->next = pre->next;
                pre->next = temp;
            } else {
                temp->next = head;
                head = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

---

@qwn, asked me to have the different names of `next` node pointer and the temp node.
@Jonathan Leffler, asked me to provide the complete code. So, here it is,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node{
    char *name;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node* insert_node(node *head, char *name);
void print_links(node *head);
void free_links(node *head);
void parser(char *string);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    char *string = "file1a.txt/file1b.txt/too_deep/dir1/file2a.txt/";
    parser(string);
}

void parser(char *s){
    node *head;
    char *tokens;
    char *string = strdup(s);
    tokens = strtok(string, "/");
    while (tokens != NULL){
        //printf("%s\n", tokens);
        head = insert_node(head, tokens);
        tokens = strtok(NULL, "/");
    }
    print_links(head);
    free_links(head);
    return;
}

node* insert_node(node *head, char *name){
    node *temp, *pre, *ptr;
    temp = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->name = name;
    temp->next = NULL;

    if (!head){
        head = temp;
    } else {
        pre = NULL;
        ptr = head;
        // problem lies in this while loop
        while(ptr && (strcmp(ptr->name, name) < 0) ){
            printf("here\n");
            pre = ptr;
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        printf("out\n");
        if (!ptr){
            pre->next = temp;
        } else {
            if(pre){
                temp->next = pre->next;
                pre->next = temp;
            } else {
                temp->next = head;
                head = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: How about using `gdb`?

Comment: I think you try to access `name` of the `next` even if the `next` node is NULL which will seg fault.

Comment: @qwn, well, the first half of the condition make sure that `next` do exist. If it does exist then there should be `next->name`. That's what I think.

Comment: You are right. `next = next->next` is this valid? having the same variable name as the pointer?

Comment: @qwn, I am pretty sure it is smart enough to know the difference. Your concern is right, I should not have the same name. I have changed the names, unfortunately, that wasn't a problem.

Comment: See [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  Also, show the MCVE ([MCVE]) that illustrates the problem.  One function that is not `main()` does not make a C program, and the problem could easily be in how you're using this function.  We can't tell how you're (mis)using it.  You've also not shown any data that you've entered.  Is it the first entry or the second or some random entry or what?

Comment: @rkosegi, `gdb` is saying that something is wrong with my `strcmp`, I have no idea what. This is what I am geeting `#0  0x00007ffff7ac9e5a in __strcmp_sse2_unaligned () from /lib64/libc.so.6`

Comment: problem in while llop where you are assigning **next = next->next;**.

Comment: MCVE - please show how/where you are calling insert_node() and the storage class of its arguments, eg. 'name', because of 'temp->name = name;' - pointer assignment only,

Comment: I have updated with the full code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `head` variable is not initialized in `parser()`, and its undefined value is passed to `insert_node()`, so the first access to the value with `if(!head)` triggers Undefined Behavior.

The result is most probably 'false' (as in your case), so the control is passed to the `else` branch, where the `head` value is copied to the `ptr` variable. Consequently `ptr` is not NULL in the `while` loop's condition, so `ptr->name` is accessed prior to `strcmp` call – and you're lucky this time UB results in the memory access error at the location 'pointed to' by `ptr`, which results in a crash.

Solution:
Expand the declaration by  initializer:

```
    node* head = NULL;
```

Comment: this is one of the examples why I hate C. I have wasted my whole day trying to figure this out. Thank you so much!!! I owe you a cold one.

Comment: @HafizTemuri BTW, are you aware you do not `free()` the `strdup`-ed string? This may cause a memory leak in general application. OTOH be aware that in your list's nodes you store pointers pointing _into_ that string, so if you free the string you should do it _after_ deallocating a list.

Comment: @HafizTemuri if you had followed the advice of rkosegi, and stepped thorugh with your debugger, you would have noticed that 'head = temp;' was not executed on the first run through insert_node(), and so understood that 'head' was not NULL and invalid at that time.  Debugging skills are absolutely essential for software development in any language.

Comment: @MartinJames I suppose you indended to post your comment under the Hafiz's question rather then under my answer... Anyway, `head` being invalid does **not** follow from `head=temp` assignement not being executed yet, but rather from `head` itself being not initialized.

Comment: @MartinJames, I do have the debugging skills, thank you very much! I did know exactly what line causing the problem, but I wasn't sure why. The reason why I hate C is that it does not let you get away with anything, whereas other languages do a lot of stuff for you. Everyone is entitled to have their own opinion.

Comment: @CiaPan, I completely forgot to free `strdup` strings in my whole application. Thanks for reminding me. I am planning to `malloc` all my strings at some point, because I heard `strdup` is not a standard C function.